# Scala Play JDBC Issue

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm confused by the following JDBC error.

> [JdbcSQLException: Column "HASH" not found; SQL statement: insert into
>   HashToUrl (hash, url) values ( hash, url ) [42122-158]]

**1.sql**

```
# Tasks schema

# --- !Ups

CREATE TABLE HashToUrl  (
    Hash integer,
    Url  varchar(255)
);

# --- !Downs

DROP TABLE HashToUrl;
```

Is my insert statement bad?

**model/Task.scala**

```
def create(hash: Int, url:String) {
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
        SQL("insert into HashToUrl (hash, url) values ({hash, url})")
        .executeUpdate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe a lower/upper case issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Anorm, but I don't think it automatically binds data to parameter.

```
SQL("insert into HashToUrl (hash, url) values ({hash, url})")
    .on("hash" -> hash, "url" -> url)
    .executeUpdate()
```

(I don't think it's your current error, check character case like said nico)

Answer (score 0):

Which database are you using? For example, PostgreSQL is case-sensitive. If so, you should specify not 'hash' but 'Hash' in SQL.

```
SQL("insert into HashToUrl (Hash, Url) values ({hash, url})")...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL("insert into HashToUrl (hash, url) values ({hash, url})")
    .executeUpdate()
```

should be

```
SQL("insert into HashToUrl (hash, url) values ({hash, url})").on('hash -> hash, 'url-> url).executeUpdate()
```